# Getting compile errors, I don't uderstand

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, timepicker

I am a very frustrated newbee!
I really don't know where to start.  I have an app based on the one in the dummies book.  Got it working.  Then tried to convert it to use the WIMMOne dialogs for time and date.  After a bunch of false starts I loaded one of their samples and got it working.  I then isolated the code in that and pasted in my sample.  I cannot get past errors.  (It doesn't help that eclipse constantly adds some of its own.  Sometimes I load the source and all statements, including imports, are marked as errors, sometimes I get the R.id,--- in error, I have even had it marked comments as in error.

However, I have cleaned it and reloaded it enough times that I think I am down to a few real errors.

There are a couple basic differences between mine and the sample code:
The sample is one big activity java file, mine is in a fragment.  Mine had a separate java file for the time dialog.  The sample was in the one file, so I coded mine that way.  Mine has two menus, a list from which the user goes to a "detail" menu.  The sample is all one screen.

There were 2 JAR files from WIMM, I have both in my libs.

To save space I included the first part, where I am getting 3 errors, but will be happy to provide it all if needed.

The first is the sample.  It works and even with my commented code, there are no compile errors:
Thanks,Clark

```
    package com.test.medication;


    /**************************
     * Java Imports
     **************************/
    import java.util.Calendar;

    /******************************
     * android imports
     ******************************/
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.format.Time;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    /******************************
     * Wimm imports
     ******************************/
    import com.wimm.framework.app.LauncherActivity;
    import com.wimm.framework.app.TextInputDialog;
    import com.wimm.framework.app.TimePickerDialog;
    import com.wimm.framework.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSelectedListener;

    public class MedicationsActivity extends LauncherActivity 
    {


        /****************************
         * private globals
         ****************************/
        private TextInputDialog textDialog;
        private TimePickerDialog timeDialog;
        private long msToCount = 0;
        private static String textInput = "please enter pills";
        private EditText timeDisplay;
        private EditText pillsDisplay;
        private long newMs = 0;
        private int Hours;
        private int Minutes;
        private static int hoursToCount = 0;
        private static int minutesToCount = 0;
        private Calendar c ;
        private int mIndex = 0;
        private boolean textEntered = false;

    // get an store the simple name of this class into an String
    private static final String TAG = MedicationsActivity.class.getSimpleName();


     /***********************
     *  define constants
     **********************/
    // define id for both the time dialog, and the enter pills dialog
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int PILLS_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    // the actions for the intent definitions posted 
    public static final String ACTION_POST_NOTIFICATION     = "com.test.medication.action.POST";
    public static final String ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION   = "com.test.medication.action.UPDATE";
    public static final String ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION   = "com.test.medication.action.CANCEL";

    //delay between views
    private static final int viewDelay      = 5000;  // ms

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        //-----------------------------------------------
        // initialize time entry listener
            // pass current state
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // open up main layout resource and upload into wimm 
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Log.d("MedsMC","S onCrt-1");

            // Subscribe listeners to the buttons and text fields
            Button okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
            Button pillsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enterPills);
            pillsDisplay = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entryMeds);
            timeDisplay = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entryTime); 
            Log.d("MedsMC","S onCrt-2L" + timeDisplay);

            // set up the time picker dialog with initial time
            //and subscribe a listener upon the press of ok n the time dialog
            TimePickerDialog myTimerHandler = new TimePickerDialog(this);
            myTimerHandler.setTime(6, 0);
            myTimerHandler.setTimeSelectedListener(timeSetListener);
            Log.d("MedsMC","S onCrt-3myTH" + timeDisplay);
```

This is my latest with 3 of the errors: the "TimePickerDialog" is used in several places and always has an error.

```
package com.dummies.android.taskreminder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Calendar;  
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
//import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;   //
import android.os.Bundle;  //
import android.os.Handler; 
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;  //
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button; //
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;  //
//import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;  //
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.app.Dialog; //
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/*******************************************
 * wimm imports
 */

import com.wimm.framework.app.LauncherActivity;
//import com.wimm.framework.app.TextInputDialog;
mport com.wimm.framework.app.TimePickerDialog;
import com.wimm.framework.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSelectedListener;
//import com.wimm.framework.app.DatePickerDialog;
//import com.wimm.framework.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSelectedListener;


public class ReminderEditFragment
             extends Fragment
             implements OnDateSetListener,
           //             OnTimeSetListener,
                        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 
   {

    private TimePickerDialog timeDialog;
    //private EditText timeDisplay;

    private static int intHours = 0;
    private static int intMinutes = 0;
    private long lngNewMs = 0;
    private Calendar calC ;

    // define constent to be used 
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int PILLS_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    public static final String DEFAULT_EDIT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "editFragmentTag"; 
    private EditText mTitleText;

    private EditText mBodyText;
    //private TextInputDialog textDialog;
    //private TextInputDialog mBodyDialog;

    //private TimePickerDialog timeDialog;
    private Button mTimeButton;


    //private Button timeDisplay;

    //private TimePickerDialog mTimeDialog;

    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mConfirmButton;
    private Calendar mCalendar;

    //OK
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
       {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // save the calendar instance
            outState.putSerializable(CALENDAR, mCalendar);
       }

    private long mRowId;        


    //OK
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       { 
        //-- house keeping
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("RemindEF","S onCrt");

        if (savedInstanceState != null &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(CALENDAR) )
           {
             mCalendar = (Calendar) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(CALENDAR);
             Log.d("RemindEF","Cs onCrt:" + mCalendar);
           }
        else
           {
             mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             Log.d("RemindEF","C onCrt:" + mCalendar);
           }
        Bundle arguments = getArguments(); 

        //-----------------
        //  retrieve row id from list
        if (arguments != null)
           {
            mRowId = arguments.getLong(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_ROWID);
            Log.d("RemindEF","A onCrt:" + mRowId);
               }                

        //-----------------------------------------------
        // initialize time entry listener
    //???????? ERROR: The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type ReminderEditFragment
           setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);

           Log.d("RemindEF","X onCrt");

    //???????ERROR: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ReminderEditFragment
           mTimeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reminder_time); 
           Log.d("MedsMC","S onCrt-2L" + mTimeButton);

    //?????? ERROR: The constructor TimePickerDialog(ReminderEditFragment) is undefined
            TimePickerDialog myTimerHandler = new TimePickerDialog(this);
            myTimerHandler.setTime(6, 0);
            myTimerHandler.setTimeSelectedListener(timeSetListener);
            Log.d("MedsMC","S onCrt-3myTH" + mTimeButton);
```

Comment: The error messages indicate you're trying to invoke methods on a class that don't exist.  In the example code, the method named _setContentView()_ is part of the class _MedicationsActivity_, which extends _LauncherActivity_ (which presumeably extends _Activity_).  Maybe your class should _also_ extend _Activity_... although each class can only extend one class in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying code that was being used in an `Activity` and using it in a `Fragment`.

This will require some modification.

```
setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
```

This is used to set the layout. It is called inside `onCreate()`.

```
mTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);
```

This is used to get a reference to a certain View.

In a `Fragment`, to set the layout and find views we override `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_edit, null);
    mTimeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.reminder_time); 
    return v;
}
```

```
TimePickerDialog myTimerHandler = new TimePickerDialog(this);
```

The argument of the `TimePickerDialog` constructor is a `Context` object.
In an Activity `this` would be valid because it would reference the Activity's instance.
In a Fragment you should call `getActivity()` instead.

```
TimePickerDialog myTimerHandler = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciate the replies! (also @stephen-c,@dima)
I had a feeling it was due the fragment, but the "dummies" book implied that is how to do it, so I complied.  With your help, it ran and I got my list, selected and to this screen.  I am down to one error, I have a "showDialog(int)".  In reading various postings, that doesn’t work in fragments either. This is a very simple app but needs datePicker and text. so I think the easiest step is to move my code to the activity and not use fragments at least on this screen.  With a smart watch, I don't need to deal with orientation.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly an attempt to explain what the compilation errors *mean*.

---

> ERROR: The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type ReminderEditFragment

You are calling a `setContentView` method on `ReminderEditFragment`, but `ReminderEditFragment` has no such method.

It appears that you are trying to call `Activity.setContentView` on `this`.  But `this` is not an `Activity` ... because of your refactoring.

> ERROR: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ReminderEditFragment

Same as above, for a different `Activity` method.

(I'm not an Android expert, but it seems that you are doing things on a Fragment that you should be doing on an Activity.  Perhaps, your Fragment class needs a reference to some Activity instance that it can use for those calls ... ?)

---

> ERROR: The constructor TimePickerDialog(ReminderEditFragment) is undefined

The standard `TimePickerDialog` class has 2 constructors, but neither of them take a single `ReminderEditFragment` argument.  You need to look at the `TimePickerDialog` javadoc ...

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't run your app, when active XML file. 
If you did it, clean project and  remove generated file

2) Аlways save project `Ctrl + Shift + S` after adding widgets to layout. After saving will generated an addresses of this widgets and will have no problem with 
 
`The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ReminderEditFragment`